# Custom loss function in Keras for weighting missclassified samples

Tags: python, keras, classification, regression, loss-function

Assume that `y_true` and `y_pred` are in [-1,1]. I want a weighted mean-square-error loss function, in which the loss for samples that are positive in the `y_true` and negative in `y_pred` or vice versa are weighted by `exp(alpha)`. Here is my code:

```
import keras.backend as K
alpha = 1.0
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
     se = K.square(y_pred-y_true)
     true_label = K.less_equal(y_true,0.0)
     pred_label = K.less_equal(y_pred,0.0)
     return K.mean(se * K.exp(alpha*K.cast(K.not_equal(true_label,pred_label), tf.float32)))
```

And here is a plot of this loss function. Different curves are for different values for `y_true`.
[image]

I want to know:

- Whether this is a valid loss function, since it is not differentiable in 0?
- Is my code correct?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this type of loss function to handle imbalance dataset

```
def focal_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   gamma = 2.0, alpha = 0.25
   pt_1 = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1), y_pred, tf.ones_like(y_pred))
   pt_0 = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 0), y_pred, tf.zeros_like(y_pred))
   return -K.sum(alpha * K.pow(1. - pt_1, gamma) * K.log(pt_1))-K.sum((1-alpha) * K.pow(pt_0, gamma) * K.log(1. - pt_0))
```

from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-imbalanced-datasets-in-deep-learning-f48407a0e758) source